# Entering the input values during run-time of a C++ program (./filename.out)

Tags: c++, g++

I want to enter the user input during the run-time of a C++ program i.e during ./a.out
Illustration : ./a.out input1 input2

The C++ program is :

## Program to add two numbers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int c = a + b;
    cout << "The sum of two numbers is : " << c << "\n";
}
```

Now please help me to enter the values of a and b at the run-time while running its output file in linux terminal.

Comment: It seems you want to pass the input parameters as command line arguments while running the exe.If that be the case You should have a look at arguments `main()` takes, `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: I have updated my question, Yes I want to use command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (don't forget to include appropriate headers):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if ( argc == 3 ) // command line has three arguments, the program, arg1 and arg2
   {
     int sum = atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2]);
     cout<<"The sum of two numbers is : "<< sum << endl;
   }
   else
   {
     cout << "wrong number of arguments, expected two numbers" << endl;
     cout << "yourprogramname {number1} {number2}" << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Flyphe, No, it will return 0 if there's an error or if the number was 0. C++11 provides `stoi`, though, which certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

For many simple uses, [Boost Program.Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html) provides much of the boilerplate code to process command line arguments.  From the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html):

```
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);    

if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    return 1;
}

if (vm.count("compression")) {
    cout << "Compression level was set to " 
 << vm["compression"].as<int>() << ".\n";
} else {
    cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    cout << a+b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will take commandline arguments and print them. atoi converts a string to an int.

Answer (score -2):

Use redirection:

```
./yourprogram < input1
```

works both under Linux console and MSDos.

Comment: -1:  OP is asking how to extract the command line arguments, not how to pipe.